# Redirect from method in Vue.js with Vue-router older than version 1.x.x

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I'm not much of a frontend developer but I know enough javascript to do the minimum.

I'm trying to plug into a last piece of login however my vue components are:

```
"vue-resource": "^0.9.3",
"vue-router": "^0.7.13"
```

I'm not experienced enough to move up to v1 or v2 respectively.
I would like to achieve something similar to [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/redirect-from-method-in-vuejs-with-vue-router).

However I'm not getting a successful redirect.

my app.js file:

````
var router = new VueRouter();
...
import Auth from './services/auth.js';

router.beforeEach(transition => {
    if(transition.to.auth &&!Auth.authenticated)
    {
        transition.redirect('/login');
    }
    else
    {
        transition.next();
    }
});
```
In my login.js file
```
methods: {
            /**
             * Login the user
             */
            login(e) {

                e.preventDefault();

                this.form.startProcessing();

                var vm = this;

                this.$http.post('/api/authenticate',
                    {   email                   :   this.form.email,
                        password                :   this.form.password
                    })
                    .then(function(response){
                                vm.form.finishProcessing();
                                localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
                                vm.$dispatch('authenticateUser');
                            },
                            function(response) {
                                if(response.status == 401)
                                {
                                    let error = {'password': ['Email/Password do not match']};
                                    vm.form.setErrors(error);
                                }else{
                                    vm.form.setErrors(response.data);
                                }
                            });
            }
        }
````

I tried to do as suggested:

```
vm.form.finishProcessing();
   localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
   vm.$dispatch('authenticateUser');
   vm.$route.router.go('/dashboard');
```

However all it did was append the url on top.
I see that the 3 previous events were successfully done but not the redirect.

it went from:
http://dev.homestead.app:8000/login#!/
to
http://dev.homestead.app:8000/login#!/dashboard

when I need the entire page to go to:
http://dev.homestead.app:8000/login/dashboard#1/

I think i have a missing concept in order to do the redirect correctly.

**UPDATE**

As per suggested i have added `param: append => false` but nothing happens.

what i did afterward was within app.js create a method called redirectLogin() with console.log() outputs - that worked. what i did further is i put  `vm.$route.router.go` inside there and called the method via `vm.$dispatch('redirectLogin');` and that also didn't work.

**NOTE**:

The HTML is being rendered in Laravel first. the route I originally had (and working) as login/dashboard and that route is available via normal Laravel route. the blade is being rendered via view template.

So far I've been trying to vue redirect over to login/dashboard (not working) perhaps I should somehow remove `login/dashboard` and use the `route.map` and assign `login/dashboard`?

I would rather keep the `login/dashboard` as a `laravel` route due to authentication and other manipulation.

Comment: Do you have `dashboard` in your router config?

Comment: @flyingSmurfs no? in my router mapping I have / and a subroute. majority of the pages are rendered via backend and then rendered through vue.js. so i have a regular html (header/footer) and then I let vue render the body depending on which page you have landed.

Answer (score 3):

For **Vue 2**

`this.$router.push('/path')`

Comment: This seems to update the URL but it doesn't re-trigger any of the code in `created`? In my case the new route calls the same component, so I was expecting it to re-trigger `created` on that same component.

Answer (score 1):

As par the [documentation](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/1.0/docs/en/api/go.md), `router.go` appends the path in the current route, however in your case it is appending along with `#` in the router as well.

You can use param: `append`, to directly arrive at your desired destination, like following:

```
vm.$route.router.go({name: '/login/dashboard#1/', params: {append: false}})
```

---

### Edited

If it is not happening, you can try `$window.location` method like following:

```
var url = "http://" + $window.location.host + "login/dashboard";
console..log(url);
$window.location.href = url;
```

Comment: according to what you wrote - it should have worked (i mean word for word)
However it didn't. It compiled fine but it doesn't do anything. What else do you need to know about my script that I haven't mentioned?

Comment: @azngunit81 How I see is, your code is working as documentation, as it is appending, but appending with #, thats why I am suggesting to add `param: append => false` to replace the URL, DId you get a chance to try this?

Comment: yes. nothing happens. 16hrs later nothing. ill update with a few more info maybe it will shed some light of something wrong?

Comment: @azngunit81 you can also once try `$window.location.href`, as in my edited answer.

Comment: ok, where? in the method i am presuming right? i tried and it is not tossing anything to consol

Answer (score 1):

I think their is a misunderstanding here of how vue-router works. It seems you are not wanting to load a new route with a corresponding component, rather you simply want to redirect to a new page then let that page load and in turn fire up a fresh instance of vue.

If the above is correct you don't need vue-router at all. Simply add the below when you need to load the page:

```
window.location.href = '/login/dashboard'
```

If you'd rather simulate a redirect to that page (no back button history) then:

```
window.location.replace('/login/dashboard')
```

**EDIT**

The above would be fired when you have finished all processing that the page must run to set the users state which the next page requires. This way the next page can grab it and should be able to tell the correct state of the user (logged in).

Therefore you'll want to fire the redirect when the Promise has resolved:

```
.then(function(response){
    vm.form.finishProcessing()

    // store the Auth token
    localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token)

    // not sure whether this is required as this page, and in turn this instance of vue, is about to be redirected
    vm.$dispatch('authenticateUser')

    // redirect the user to their dashboard where I assume you'd run this.$dispatch('authenticateUser') again to get their state
    window.location.replace('/login/dashboard')
```

Comment: Yes that is correct however the question is where should either of your solution be placed is the missing piece of the puzzle. Mind you that the "validation" of the redirect was done in a vue component...for some reason if i leave it there - its not triggering it and im not receiving an error. However if i do console.log it works (ie it dumps)

Comment: why this and not vm. the this has a different scope no? shouldn't we use vm since it was declared that `var vm = this;`?

Comment: you can yeah, I'm just use to using arrow syntax for thenable functions which would persist the scope of `this`. Updated answer

Comment: its not triggered inside the promise. however its triggered outside (in the dispatch) but if i do that some of the objects aren't resolved properly because its not being passed by to the parent - i think im still missing something that im not understanding.

Comment: do you mean objects been set correctly on the next page `/login/dashboard` page? Or is it redirecting before you've finsihed with this page? Only either way bacause of what you are doing (not using vue-router and a component to load your dashboard) you are destroying this instance of Vue and remounting a new version on the /login/dashboard page. Therefore  other than the localStorage - no other data will persist

Comment: did the above comment help you sort this / clear things up?